# {site_url} returns value without 'http://' string

Tags: templates, tags

In the control panel under

Admin > General Configuration

I have set the value of the field 'URL to the root directory of your site' to be the URL of my site with the leading http://

eg: http://mysite.com

When I use the tag in templates it just returns

mysite.com (without the leading http://)

This is causing issues throughout my templates - is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the config folder, you may need to set it in there with the leading HTTP too.